# Is the story of Suwaybit and Nuayman authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Once Abu Bakr and some companions went on a trading expedition to
>   Busra. Various people on the trip were given fixed duties. Suwaybit
>   ibn Harmalah was made responsible for food and provisions. An-Nuayman
>   was among the group and on the way he became hungry and asked Suwaybit
>   for some food. Suwaybit refused and an-Nuayman said to him: “Do you
>   know what I would yet do with you?” and went on to warn and threaten
>   him but still Suwaybit refused. An-Nuayman then went to a group of
>   Arabs in the market and said to them: “Would you like to have a strong
>   and sturdy slave whom I can sell to you.” They said “of Course and
>   An-Nuayman went on: “He has a swift tongue and is very articulate. He
>   will resist you and say: ‘I am free.’ But don’t listen to him” The men
>   paid the price of the slave – ten pieces of gold and An-Nuayman
>   accepted it and appeared to complete the transaction with
>   business-like efficiency. The buyers accompanied him to fetch theft
>   purchase.
>
> Pointing to Suwaybit, he said: “This is the slave whom I sold to you.”
>   The men took hold of Suwaybit and he shouted for dear life and
>   freedom. “I am free”. I am Suwaybit ibn Harmalah…” But they paid no
>   attention to him and dragged him off by the neck in shackles as they
>   would have done with any slave.
>
> All the while, an-Nuayman did not laugh or batter an eyelid. He
>   remained completely calm and serious while Suwaybit continued to
>   protest bitterly. Suwaybit’s fellow travelers, realizing what was
>   happening, rushed to fetch Abu Bakr, the leader of the caravan, who
>   came running as fast as he could. He explained to the purchasers what
>   had happened and so they released Suwaybit and had their money
>   returned. Abu Bakr then laughed heartily and so did Suwaybit and
>   an-Nuayman. Back in Madinah, when the episode was recounted to the
>   Prophet and his companions, they all laughed even more.

The above can be found online on;

1. An-Nuayman ibn Amr: The Companion Who Made the Prophet Laugh
   by Yusuf Abdul-Alim | Dec 21, 2018 | Islamic History, The Faith; Link: https://intellectinislam.com/category/the-faith/islamic-history/
2. Al-Nuayman ibn Amr - Wikipedia

Comment: It is narrated in [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/64), [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/22389#p1) etc.

Answer (score 1):

The link above to Sunan ibn Majah is broken, here is the fixed: https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3719

In Sunan ibn Majah it is Da'if. In Musnad Ahmad, it says it is Da'if because of Zan'ah bin Salih. I would err on the side of caution.